# Is there a Gem for simplifying POST to API via curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen API's such as `https://stripe.com/` or the new `https://pin.net.au/` that use a very simple and convenient POST approach. Instead of sending the object through JSON it send it as post attributes and values and the return is json.

```
curl https://api.pin.net.au/1/charges \
-u your-api-key: \
-d "amount=400" \
-d "description=test charge" \
-d "email=roland@pin.net.au" \
-d "ip_address=203.192.1.172" \
-d "card[number]=5123456789012346" \
```

My question there any Gem available to do this on Rails? I can understand what's going on underneath this, but I wanted to make sure if there's a Gem that do this seamless without further changing my current default implementation.

Comment: How about [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)?

Comment: Looks interesting but I don't know how it does apply to my question.

Comment: KL means that HTTParty's post method does what you want.  It is a 'gem available to do this on Rails'

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to create or consume such APIs?

To consume:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

resp = RestClient.post(
  'https://vtUQeOtUnYr7PGCLQ96Ul4zqpDUO4sOE:@api.stripe.com/v1/charges', 
  { 
    :amount => 400, 
    :currency => 'usd', 
    :description => "charge for site@stripe.com", 
    :card => { 
      :number => '4242424242424242', 
      :exp_month => 12, 
      :exp_year => 2012, 
      :cvc => 123 
    } 
  })

JSON.parse(resp)
```

For creating these APIs you can use something like:

https://github.com/intridea/grape

https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants